# Python functions in exec() not being added to globals/locals dict

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, exec

I'm working with python's `exec()` function. I'm trying to import a module and define a function that uses that module in one `exec()` call, and then call that function from another `exec()` call.

Like this:

```py
code1 = "import time
         def foo(i):
             time.sleep(1)
             print(i)"
code2 = "foo('hello')"

custom_globals, custom_locals = {}, {}

exec(code1, custom_globals, custom_locals)
exec(code2, custom_globals, custom_locals)
```

However, when I run this code, I get the error `name 'time' is not defined`. This is really confusing, because if I do either of these:

- set the value of `code2` to just `time.sleep(1)`
- set the foo's code to just `print(i)` (without the `time` call)

the script will execute without error. Am I misunderstanding something about `exec()`? I know that imported modules are stored in `globals/locals` but I guess I'm not really sure about methods. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: After the first `exec()` call, `custom_globals` has its default value and `custom_locals` looks like this:
`{'time': <module 'time' (built-in)>, 'foo': <function foo at 0xa159968c0>}`

Comment: So, by passing a different dict as a custom locals, you've made it execute as if it were in a class scope (in the global scope, `locals() is globals()` but the `foo` you defined doesn't create a closure in `exec`, it looks in the global scope, and `time` isn't there

Comment: @superbrain edited

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga are you recommending I just use one dict instead of two separate dicts? Will that store both globals and locals?

Comment: Yes. And re-reading the docs: "If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition." so that local scope won't be an enclosing scope!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution per [@juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) was to use just one vars dict instead of a `global` dict and a `local` dict, because "If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition."